# Browse/iterate each input element of a div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="arraydiffid">
    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="3" />

    <div class='hello'>
        somethings
    </div

    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="4" />

    <span>hello</span>

    <input type="hidden" name="array_diff[]" value="5" />        
</div>
```

How can I browse only all "input type hidden" children? (and not the rest, as div or span) I tried :

```
$('#arraydiffid>children').each(function(){
    alert($(this).value());
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#arraydiffid > input[type=hidden]').each(function() {

    if($(this).val()>=param) 
       $(this).val($(this).val()+1);
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yeah this works. Only problem is that it get the value as string. So, if i write (into function()) this if($(this).val()>=param) $(this).val($(this).val()+1); it doesnt add 1, just it put 1 at the end of the string.

Comment: Use parseInt() to make sure it's treated as an integer. parseInt($(this).val()) + 1

Comment: @mark Use `parseInt(this.value, 10)` to turn the string into an integer

Answer (score 0):

It might be beneficial to wrap these in a form as thats the way input is supposed to be displayed.  Then you can use jQuery.serialize to access the data.

```
<form id="arraydiffid>
  <input />
  ....
</form>

$("#arraydiffid").serialize(); //array_diff%5B%5D=0&array_diff....
```

I'm not up to speed on my pseudo array notation, I believe that the way you have you setup your inputs, it will require a jQuery plugin to use that notation.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/N7ZC4/